# Context Menu on left click using oncontextmenu and js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I have a table where by clicking any row I can access context menu

```
<tr oncontextmenu="return showContextMenu(event,'@item.SomeValue')"  style="cursor: pointer;">
```

The event of showing the context menu looks like this:

```
var contextMenu = document.getElementById('contextMenu');

 function showContextMenu(event, elemId) {
            contextMenu.style.display = 'block';
            contextMenu.style.left = (event.pageX - 220) + 'px';
            contextMenu.style.top = (event.pageY - 48) + 'px';
        }
```

and event of closing context menu this way:

```
window.onclick = hideContextMenu;
function hideContextMenu() {
    contextMenu.style.display = 'none';
}
```

The context menu looks like this:

```
<div id="contextMenuPasta" class="contextMenu" >
    <ul>
        <li  id="renomearCMid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRenomearPasta"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil" ></i> Renomear Pasta</span></li>
        <li  id="removerCMid"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExcluirPasta"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i> Remover Pasta</span></li>
        <li  id="adicionarCMid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNovaPasta"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Adicionar Pasta</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any way to change right click mouse to the left click, in order to show context menu? 
Thank You for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

1. in tr tag instead of using 'oncontextmenu' I used simply 'onclick'
2. delete 'hideContextMenu' function
3. instead, use this

   ```
   window.onclick = function (event) {
       if(event["path"][0].tagName != "TD" ){
           contextMenu.style.display = 'none';
       }
   };
   ```